# fourier series of $f(x)=\sin(25t)\cos(t)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I got a trouble with this .

$B(n)$ was $\displaystyle \frac{2\pi}{25} \int_0^{\pi/25} \sin(25t) \cos(t) \sin \left( \frac{25nt}2 \right) \, dt$

and semi -result was $\displaystyle \frac{2\pi}{25} \int_0^{\pi/25} \left( \frac{\sin(26t)+\sin(24t)} 2 \right) \sin\left(\frac{25nt} 2 \right) \, dt$.

how can degrade this perfectly? it keeps teasing me...

Comment: I have taken the liberty of changing $dx$ to $dt$ and adding the missing $dt$ in one integral. And of cleaning up the typesetting.

Comment: Please look at the proper way of coding things like $a\sin b$, as in my edits to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I wouldn't go to calculate the coefficients with the projection. Instead, I would use the formula for $\cos{a}\sin{b} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sin(a+b) + \sin(b-a)\right)$. Use this and the uniqueness of representation.

Comment: yes but after that I'm blocked $(\frac{sin(26t)+sin(24t)}{2})sin(\frac{25n}{2})$

Comment: @matthew No need to calculate the integral. You know that $f(t) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}B(n)\sin(\omega_n t)$. Also, you know that $f(t) = \sin(25t)\cos(t)$. What happens (after you use the trig identity) when you equate the two expressions?

Comment: oh I understand..  I confused that concept . tnx!!